# SharePoint 2010: This page is not using a valid page layout

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint 2010 
I have an enterprise wiki site, that I exported and imported from one farm to another.  However, I exported it form a site collection root site, to a sub site in another  site collection. When I browse to any page that was created with the Enterprise wiki template, I get the error:

This page is not using a valid page layout.  To correct the problem, edit page settings and select a valid page layout."

The page layout is showing as Basic Page.  And works ok for new pages created.  How can I fix the page layout, that is in the existing pages?

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried reset to site definition

Comment: any chance you could publish the powershell code you used to initial fix this problem ? it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug. If you import a publishing site, the pages do not have the correct link to the page layout.  No way to fix this through the UI.  I had to use [PowerShell](http://tinyurl.com/4ht7a49).

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Mahesh's Blog](http://maheshvd.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/page-layout-issue/) to this [MS Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2459149) and used the Manage Content and Structure tool to change the Page Layout. Quite strange (this error seems to be a downstream  error from a page that failed to upgrade from SharePoint 2007 and had a XsltListViewWebPart which had an invalid GroupBy setting).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simpler /similar version of the code in the link copied in case the original goes away (I've added notes about what needs to be changed)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing")

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://web/you/are/modifying";  #Change web that you're modifying on this line

$spPubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web);
$pages = $spPubWeb.PagesList;

foreach($item in $pages.Items)
{
  $pubPage = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage]::GetPublishingPage($item)

  $url = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue($pubPage.ListItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId]::PageLayout].ToString())

  if($url -ne $null)
  {   
    if($url.Url -match 'NameOfPageLayout')  #Change Page layout name on this line
      {  
      $newurl = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue("http://new/rootweb/_catalogs/masterpage/NewPageLayout.aspx, NewPageLayoutName")  #Change URL and name on this line
      $pubPage.Name
      $pubPage.CheckOut()
      $pubPage.ListItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId]::PageLayout] = $newurl
      $pubPage.ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()

      $pubPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn("Fixed URL to page layout.", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn);
      }
  }

}
```